# Find sum of nested list using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

Find the sum of nested list using recursion

```
lst = [1,2,[3,4],[5,6]]
def findSum(values,sum,idx):
    if len(values) == idx:
        return sum
    if isinstance(values[idx],list):
       return findSum(values[idx],sum,0)
    else:
        sum = sum + values[idx]
        return findSum(values,sum,idx+1)

print(findSum(lst,0,0))
```

Output should be `21` but I am getting only `10` last index subarray([5,6]) not getting calculated.

Can anyone suggest me, what I am doing wrong in the logic?

Comment: Let's avoid using the Python `built-in` `sum` as your variable name. That's dangerous...

Comment: Do you really need recursion for this?  Because if your `list` is huge one, you might have issue to handle.

Comment: The problem is that your program will `return` whenever any `sub list` sum is finished at any index in your `main list`. For example `[[1,2],3,4,[5,6]]` will always give you `3` as you have `sub list` in the beginning and your program thinks that it finished computing. *Your exit condition is the reason for that*

Comment: As you can run it here -  https://pythontutor.com/      You will find out the `recursion` stop after it processed the `[5, 6]` and exit.  At that point, the total is 10. and exit....

Comment: The problem is that you're ending the recursion when you get to the end of any list, not just the outer list. One solution would be to handle the second case differently: `return findSum(values[idx], sum,0) + findSum(values[idx+1:],0,0)`, then also handle the case of an empty list. On mobile; there are better implementations with larger changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can recurse through the list as shown below

```
def recur_sum(lst):
    s = 0
    for x in lst:
        if type(x) == list:
            s += recur_sum(x)
        else:
            s += x
    return s


lst = [1,2,[3,4],[5,6]]
print(recur_sum(lst))
```

**EDIT:** The problem with OP's code is, the code is not moving forward after its done processing a sublist and returns from there.

Answer (score 0):

There are just some good pointers earlier about the origin codes problem, so I am not going to repeat here.

This is just a simpler approach for this problem, maybe as a reference.

```
A = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5,6]]


def sum_lst(A):
    total = 0
    
    for x in A:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            total += sum_lst(x)
        else:
            total += x
            
    return total
    
print(sum_lst(A))      # 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun: a recursive approach using [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce).

A (mathematical) recursion is defined by an initial value and a relationship between a certain terms and its previous ones. The initial value can be specified by the `initializer` parameter of `reduce` and, in this case, it is set to `0`. The recursive function can be passed as a parameter to `reduce`.

Notice:

- no `for`-loop is required
- only two nested level list supported

```
from functools import reduce


def recursive_relationship(i, j):
    if isinstance(j, list):
        if j:
            return recursive_relationship(i+j[0], j[1:])
        else:
            return i
    return i + j


lst = [1,2,[3,4],[5,6], [8]]
#lst = [[1, 2], [1, 2,3], [1]]

print(reduce(recursive_relationship, lst, 0))
```